# How to use Parallel.ForEach to display the values of IDictionary?

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am a C# enthusiast and I am playing with Parallel.ForEach method. I am trying to display the environment variables on a given system using the following code:

```
IDictionary vars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();

Parallel.ForEach(vars, (envVar) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", envVar.Key, envVar.Value);
});
```

However I end up with this error:

> Error 3 The type arguments for method
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner<TSource>,
>   System.Action<TSource,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,long>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I am pretty sure I am missing a cast but whatever I tried I couldn't make it work.
Can you help me out?

Comment: That only works with generic collections.  Also, there is no reason to use parallelism here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDictionary.GetEnumerator()` returns an `IDictionaryEnumerator`, which has a property `Entry` that returns the current element (both key and value) of type `DictionaryEntry`, so that's the type you are using:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var envVars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();

        Parallel.ForEach( envVars.Cast<DictionaryEntry>(), ev =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", ev.Key, ev.Value );
            } );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I accepted Moho's answer as this was exactly what I wanted to do. However SLaks is also right. When I use Parallel.Foreach in this particular case it appears to be ~100 times slower than the regular foreach (00:00:00.0411613 vs 00:00:00.0000359)

Comment: This is somewhat confusing answer, I think. `IDictionaryEnumerator` does have `Entry`, but that's not what `Cast` uses; instead, it uses the `object`-returning `Current` property and then casts its result.

Comment: The `Entry` property in the documentation is a way to determine the type of the elements, in this case `DictionaryEntry`.  I simply walked through my logic nailing down the type of the element.